# PySpark Handling Timeinterval in Structured Streaming

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, streaming, spark-streaming

I'm approaching streaming computation with Spark, in particular with the PySpark framework. I have a lot of doubts about how works sliding windows and batches. I've read these resources before to write here:

1. From Spark documentation: [Spark documentation about Triggers](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#triggers)
2. From Spark documentation: [Spark documentation about Windowing](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#window-operations)
3. From StackOverFlow: [More info about Batch and Slide interval and window size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50674262/difference-between-batch-interval-sliding-interval-and-window-size-in-spark-str/50675010)
4. There are other websites and forum that more or less describe the same things

Until now this is my code:

```
spark_session = SparkSession.builder.appName("RST SQL STREAMING APPROACH").getOrCreate()
spark_session.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

userSchema = StructType()\
                .add("timestamp", TimestampType())\
                .add("id", StringType())\
                .add("vessel", StringType())\
                .add("velocity", StringType())\
                .add("distance", StringType())\
                .add("drift_angle", StringType())\
                .add('decision', StringType())

topic_data = spark_session.readStream.format('kafka')\
            .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "myServer:port")\
            .option("subscribe", "myTopic")\
            .load()


universe = topic_data.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)").select(from_json(col("value"), userSchema).alias('value')).select('value.*')

eclasses = universe.withWatermark('timestamp', '1 minute')\
    .groupBy(window('timestamp', windowDuration="30 seconds", slideDuration="15 seconds"), 'drift_angle').agg(F.collect_list('vessel').alias('EClass'))

classes = universe.withWatermark('timestamp', '1 minutes')\
    .groupBy(window('timestamp', windowDuration="30 seconds", slideDuration="15 seconds"), 'decision').agg(F.collect_list('vessel').alias('DClasses'))


universe_query = universe.writeStream.trigger(processingTime='1 seconds').outputMode("append").format("console").start()
eclasses_query = eclasses.writeStream.trigger(processingTime='1 minute').outputMode("append").format("console").start()
classes_query = classes.writeStream.trigger(processingTime='1 minute').outputMode("append").format("console").start()


universe_query.awaitTermination()
eclasses_query.awaitTermination()
classes_query.awaitTermination()
```

I'm going to explain: What I want is to group my dataset based on two features: drift_angle and decision, I need to do this aggregation two times separately for my reasons. The data that arrive are:
[image: batch1]
In particular, this is the content of the variable universe at Batch 1. My first doubt: I see that the following line of code makes it possible to process the first operation (reading data from the stream) every 1 second, Isn't it?

```
universe_query = universe.writeStream.trigger(processingTime='1 seconds').outputMode("append").format("console").start()
```

Second doubt: I know that in append mode Spark shows me only the last append data, how can I show all the data on which I'm working on?? In a few words, I wanna show on the console all the arrived data, but I can't use "complete" mode if I don't make an operation of aggregation. How can I solve?

Let's go ahead with the following part

```
eclasses = universe.withWatermark('timestamp', '1 minute')\
    .groupBy(window('timestamp', windowDuration="30 seconds", slideDuration="15 seconds"), 'drift_angle').agg(F.collect_list('vessel').alias('EClass'))

classes = universe.withWatermark('timestamp', '1 minutes')\
    .groupBy(window('timestamp', windowDuration="30 seconds", slideDuration="15 seconds"), 'decision').agg(F.collect_list('vessel').alias('DClasses'))
```

These two aggregations produce the following result on Batch 4:

[image: aggregations]

Of course, the result for me is wrong, because what I want is the result of a classic groupBy, a single row for each different value of the feature on which I'm grouping. I know that I've included the timestamp, but How can I adjust the windowDuration, slidingDuration and/or processingTime in a way to get what I want? My data are produced each 5 second. Moreover, why only at batch 4 I got this aggregation? Is it about processingTime and/or slidingDuration and WindowDuration?

My third Doubt: How processingTime works? Following my example:

```
eclasses_query = eclasses.writeStream.trigger(processingTime='1 minute').outputMode("append").format("console").start()
classes_query = classes.writeStream.trigger(processingTime='1 minute').outputMode("append").format("console").start()
```

Considering the first one with "processingTime = 1 minute", does it means that the aggregation on "drift_angle" is made every 1 minute? So, for example, if I receive a row every 5 seconds it means that my aggregation is made on about 12 rows, isn't it?
Moreover, I read that the processingTime parameter should be a multiple of the windowDuration and SlidingDuration, but I haven't found anywhere if the processingTime should be greater or smaller than windowDuration and SlidingDuration. Is there a particular formula to set the right processingTime and also for WindowDuration and SlidingDuration?

Ps: I'm working with Spark 2.4.7.